# Is zip() the most efficient way to combine arrays with respect to memory in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, zip, genfromtxt

I use numpy and have two arrays, which are read with `genfromtxt`.

They have the shape `<10000,>` according to `np.shape()`.

I want these two vectors to be in an array with the shape `<10000,2>`. For now I use:

```
x = zip(x1,x2)
```

but i am not sure if there is numpy function that does this better/more efficient. I dont think [concatenate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) does what I think (or I'm doing it wrong).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is `numpy.column_stack`:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(10)
>>> b = numpy.arange(1, 11)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> b
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
>>> numpy.column_stack((a, b))
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 8,  9],
       [ 9, 10]])
>>> numpy.column_stack((a, b)).shape
(10, 2)
```

I don't make any guarantees that this is in any way *better* than `zip` in terms of memory usage, etc, but underneath it all, it appears to rely on numpy.concatenate (which is implemented in C), so that's at least encouraging:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> print inspect.getsource(numpy.column_stack)
def column_stack(tup):
    """
    Stack 1-D arrays as columns into a 2-D array.

    Take a sequence of 1-D arrays and stack them as columns
    to make a single 2-D array. 2-D arrays are stacked as-is,
    just like with `hstack`.  1-D arrays are turned into 2-D columns
    first.

    Parameters
    ----------
    tup : sequence of 1-D or 2-D arrays.
        Arrays to stack. All of them must have the same first dimension.

    Returns
    -------
    stacked : 2-D array
        The array formed by stacking the given arrays.

    See Also
    --------
    hstack, vstack, concatenate

    Notes
    -----
    This function is equivalent to ``np.vstack(tup).T``.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> a = np.array((1,2,3))
    >>> b = np.array((2,3,4))
    >>> np.column_stack((a,b))
    array([[1, 2],
           [2, 3],
           [3, 4]])

    """
    arrays = []
    for v in tup:
        arr = array(v, copy=False, subok=True)
        if arr.ndim < 2:
            arr = array(arr, copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=2).T
        arrays.append(arr)
    return _nx.concatenate(arrays, 1)
```

Comment: It's better wrt memory usage: zip() packs each element of the arrays to separate Python objects, which has memory overhead.

Answer (score 8):

A simple test:

```
python -m timeit "import numpy as np; x, y = np.array([range(100000), range(100000,200000)]); zip(x,y)"
```

10 loops, best of 3: 32.2 msec per loop

```
python -m timeit "import numpy as np; x, y = np.array([range(100000), range(100000,200000)]); np.column_stack((x, y))"
```

10 loops, best of 3: 14.4 msec per loop